# Python need to input str

Tags: python

```
i = 0 
mylist = ['a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k']
number = [0,3,5,6,9,11]
for i in number:
  print(mylist[0])

CoolUtahResidents = ['Tan France','Post Malone', 'Sam']
for AwesomeUTPeople in CoolUtahResidents:
        print(AwesomeUTPeople)

CoolUtahResidents.append('Isaac')
print(CoolUtahResidents[4] + ' Is number ' + len(CoolUtahResidents) + ' resident')
```

Question: I get this error: IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We don't know what you're trying to do.  Your post contains too many errors for us to figure out its purpose.

Comment: What do you want to do ? We can't guess

Comment: I'm guessing maybe you want to know how to index lists?

Comment: yeah it says the list object is not collable

Comment: `CoolUtahResidents[4]` not `CoolUtahResidents(4)`.

Comment: they fixed part of it. the real problem is with the index

Comment: if someone gets how to fix it lmk

Comment: Remember that the first item in an iterable is index 0, the second is index 1, and so on. So getting `CoolUtahResidentas[4]` is actually requesting the 5th item in the list, which doesn't exist, leading to an exception.